# Calling a function interactively without adding it to the command history

Tags: advice, history-variables, m-x

In some cases, I often run the same command, say `my-common-fun`, which I call subsequently with `M-x M-p RET`, and occasionally run another command, such as `my-occasional-fun`. I want to call the latter interactively without adding it to the `command-history`, so that `M-x M-p RET` runs `my-common-fun`.

I tried this:

```
(defun my-occasional-fun ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "one occasional shortcut")
  (pop command-history))
```

This fails, probably because the function is added to the command history after it runs.

I tried with [an advice](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions):

```
(defadvice my-occasional-fun (after my-occasional-fun-after activate) (pop command-history))
```

and it also fails: I see the command `my-occasional-fun` in the history.

Can I call a function interactively without adding it to the command history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop it from `extended-command-history` alongside `command-history`

```
(defun my-occasional-fun ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "one occasional shortcut")
  (pop extended-command-history)
  (pop command-history))
```

Comment: Indeed, for me too, `(car command-history)` shows `epa-file-enable`, but `M-x M-p` shows `my-occasional-fun`.

Comment: Hmm.. looks like M-x M-p uses the minibuffer history, that's why it is not affected by command-history

Comment: Why not try to adjust `minibuffer-history` instead of command-history?

Comment: I just tried with `minibuffer-history` and I get the same results: `my-occasional-fun` still shows at the top.

Comment: `M-x` uses `extended-command-history`.

Comment: @Drew Yes, that works, thanks!